# Applying the Weekday functions shows error

Tags: excel

I am trying to highlight the weekends but when I apply the function, it shows such error, even though the column's data type is also date and I tried as general datatype as well. thanks a lot for your gently feedback and your help.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a semicolon instead of a comma? What are your regional settings?

Comment: hey man, thanks a lot. your comment solved my problem but I can not mark it as answered one!

Comment: I've posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is often because your regional settings are set to use a different separator than the comma. Try using a semicolon instead.